# Codeigniter CSRF Jquery Issue

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am confused why codeigniter wont let me use this:

```
$(function() {
    var csrf = $.cookie("<?php echo $this->config->item('csrf_cookie_name'); ?>"),
        csrfToken = "<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>";
    $('.notificationBoxClose').click(function() {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.post(url, {csrfToken: csrf}, function() {
            $('#notification').fadeOut('slow', function() {$this.remove()});
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

When I do the same exact code like this it works fine:

```
$(function() {
    var csrf = $.cookie("<?php echo $this->config->item('csrf_cookie_name'); ?>");
    $('.notificationBoxClose').click(function() {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.post(url, {<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>: csrf}, function() {
            $('#notification').fadeOut('slow', function() {$this.remove()});
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Why cant I make security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?> into a variable?

Comment: What are the errors? Is token name free of characters that could break the javascript code?

Comment: On first example you didnt define `csrfToken` variable. like ` var csrfToken = "...`. Maybe thats why

Comment: The Error is "The action you have requested is not allowed."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you can't use variables as object keys. You need to insert it like this:

```
$(function() {
    var postData = {};
    var csrfToken = "<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>";
    postData[csrfToken] = $.cookie("<?php echo $this->config->item('csrf_cookie_name'); ?>"),
    $('.notificationBoxClose').click(function() {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.post(url, postData, function() {
            $('#notification').fadeOut('slow', function() {$this.remove()});
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks that works great but I have another question if I have another two functions that I would like to be able to call the same info but they have more data they are pushing. Is there a way to make it so I can use it like `$.post(url, {username: username, email: email, password: password, postData}, function (data) {` I would like to use the csrt info as a constant

Comment: `$.post(url, $.extend(postData, userData), function(data){});` More on the function $.extend: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Comment: So I would have to make: `var userData = {}; userData[username] = username;userData[email] = email;userData[password] = password;`

Comment: No need to. The only thing you can't do is using variables as keys. `var userData = {username: username, email: email, password: password};` will work because it's like writing `var userData = {"username": username, "email": email, "password": password};`